# polynomials that have distinct roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have known some Sufficient Condition for All the Roots of a Polynomial To Be Real. Is there any sufficient condition that a polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ distinct roots? For $n=2$, it is trivial.

Comment: Have you read about [discriminants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The condition, over a field of characteristic 0 (or characteristic greater than the degree), is that the gcd of the polynomial and its derivative is 1.

Comment: @Sunni You ask for only a sufficient condition in your post. But note that this is both necessary and sufficient.